# Is it possible to get uid table in Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, users

I'm a student in a university and I can `finger` and `id` all users (students etc) through SSH.

Here is the id command

```
e147200@beluga:~$ id e201634
uid=22678(e201634) gid=3561(stat_bs) groups=3561(stat_bs)
```

Here I can see that the student with id e201634 is agraduate student (bs) at Statistics department (stat).

Is there a way to download this gid (or groups) table?

```
3561 stat_bs
3562 stat_ms
3611 chem_bs
3687 biol_bs
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server has `getent`, and allows users to view such information, you may be able to use `getent group stat_bs`. This will give you a list of users, separated by commas.

If `getent group` is disallowed, you still might be able to read the `passwd` database with `getent passwd`. You can then correlate the GID (the fourth column) with the desired group.

Comment: or perhaps `getent group stat_bs` to see all the members of the `stat_bs` group

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/adf5fdbd231199775533

Comment: Some are missing such as arme_spc and id_spc

Comment: This one works https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/9d5b6fc15de683aa2142

Answer (score 1):

reading the `/etc/group` file as @Chirag64 suggested will only yield the system-local user groups.

You might want to use `getent group` (or `getent passwd` for the user list) instead. The output is formatted in the same way as the `passwd` or `group` file (and therefore you can have a look at the respective manpages of [group](http://linux.die.net/man/5/group) and [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd) for help on the file format)

To get a list of group names and their GIDs, try the following

```
getent group|cut -d: -f1,3
```

And if you want the same format as in your example, `sed` the output:

```
getent group|cut -d: -f1,3|sed -e 's/\(^[^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the `/etc/group` file using `cat` or `less` which should contain the names and GIDs of each group with the list of users in them.

If you wish to get the UIDs of each user, you can get them from the `/etc/passwd` file.

Edit: As [Chris Down](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10762/chris-down) and [mreithub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26778/mreithub) mentioned, this is less likely to work in a university server setup since they would only show the system's local user groups and most systems are likely to have logins using NIS or LDAP or some other means.

Comment: This is unlikely to work, most universities propagate logins using NIS/LDAP/etc, not by hardcoding them.

Comment: @Chirag64, unfortunately there is something else https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/94c604f30310bfd3572e

Comment: @ChrisDown: you're right. I've added clarification in my answer. Your solution seems to solve the problem in those situations.